# Deserialize JSON to Disctionary object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Given

```
{
    "0": [
        "508",
        "New Form",
        "New Form",
        "SMART", {
            "0": [
                "1",
                "true"
            ],
            "1": [
                "1",
                "true",
                "3",
                "true"
            ],
            "2": [
                "1",
                "true",
                "3",
                "true",
                "5",
                "true"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        "187",
        "UserAccess",
        "UserAccess",
        "User Access to Smart", {
            "0": [
                "1",
                "true"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want to Deserialize with

```
var _gridData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(griddata);
```

But it gives me:

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '0[4]', line 1, position 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is not a dictionary, your values are not just strings, but objects.
You could deserialize it this way:

```
var ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object[]>>(json);
```

it won't throw exception, but than you have to decide what to do with result:

[image]

Comment: that "0" and "1".....that all are my dynamic object and that all having last field with nested element of json your result give me like {[0, [
  "508",
  "New Form",
  "New Form",
  "DPD:SMART",
  {
    "0": [
      "1",
      "true"
    ],
    "1": [
      "1",
      "true",
      "3",
      "true"
    ],
    "2": [
      "1",
      "true",
      "3",
      "true",
      "5",
      "true"
    ]
  }
]]}

Comment: This deserialize your json structure. You could either change your json, or change the deserialized data to get expected structure.

Comment: like which kind of i have to create json please suggest me

Comment: this is function which give me json from webgrid of MVC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not de-serializing a valid `Dictionary<string, string[]>` object, your object is really a `Dictionary<string, object[]>`, since, for example, for index `data[0][3]` you have a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

Comment: that "0" and "1".....that all are my dynamic object and that all having last field with nested element of json

Answer (score 0):

`string[]` => `object[]`, because last element is not a object isn't a string.

```
var _gridData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object[]>>(griddata);
```

Comment: your result give me like {[0, [
  "508",
  "New Form",
  "New Form",
  "DPD:SMART",
  {
    "0": [
      "1",
      "true"
    ],
    "1": [
      "1",
      "true",
      "3",
      "true"
    ],
    "2": [
      "1",
      "true",
      "3",
      "true",
      "5",
      "true"
    ]
  }
]]}

Comment: how can i take 4th element as string